# KeyError: 'created_at' in django rest serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error, while I am trying to save some data coming from a `POST` request to a database:

```
KeyError: 'created_at'
```

My `views.py` is as follows:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def event(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            DR_notice = serializer.data['dr_notice_period']
            DR_duration = serializer.data['dr_duration']
            DR_trigger = serializer.data['created_at']
            DR_start, DR_finish, timesteps = DR_event_timesteps(DR_notice, DR_duration, DR_trigger)
            serializer.save(user_id_event=request.user, dr_start=DR_start, dr_finish=DR_finish, timesteps=timesteps)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My `models.py` is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class Event(models.Model):
    
    user_id_event = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    dr_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_finish = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    timesteps = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_notice_period = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_request = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class Result(models.Model):

    event_id_result = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    HVAC_flex = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True))
    DHW_flex = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True))
    lights_flex = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True))
```

My `serializers.py` is as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from vpp_optimization.models import Event, Result

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('__all__')

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    HVAC_flex = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FloatField())
    DHW_flex = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FloatField())
    lights_flex = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FloatField())

    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ('__all__')
```

As I can understand `created_at` takes its value when `serializer.save()` is being called, but I have to use it earlier, in order to be able to compute the values of `dr_start`, `dr_finish` and `timesteps`.

**EDIT:** I want to mention that the `DR_event_timesteps` function calculates the values of `dr_start`, `dr_finish` and `timesteps`, which I want to save them in a database. So it is important to have the `created_at` value before calling this function.

Any idea of how can I bypass the error?

Comment: The `EventSerializer.created_at` field is `read_only` so the field won't appear in data/cleaned_data when accepting posted data

Comment: @IainShelvington But if I remove `read_only =True`, then I am getting `{"status":"error","data":{"created_at":["This field is required."]}}`, since I want to be filled automatically.

Comment: You need to remove the line `DR_trigger = serializer.data['created_at']`, the field is automatically field and won't available in the serializer data. It's not clear what `DR_event_timesteps` is or why you call it, you might need to add it to the question if it's required

Comment: @IainShelvington I need somehow to retrieve the value of `created_at`, since I need it in order to compute the values of `dr_start`, `dr_finish` and `timesteps`. So I though that the correct way is to get it through the serializer.

Comment: The serializer will not contain any data for `created_at`, why not just use `django.utils.timezone.now()` to get the current datetime instead? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now

Comment: @IainShelvington I did not use that solution, because I was not sure if the value of `created_at` is the same with the `django.utils.timezone.now()`, since there might be a delay between them.

Comment: If you need to generate and access the value of the `created_at` field before saving then you will need to remove `auto_now_add=True` from the model field so you can handle it manually, are there other places where instances of this model are created?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, there are not other places where instances of this model are created.